# XPM Performance Tuning in IIS

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 and would like to improve the performance on Tridion Experience Manager (XPM / SiteEdit).  Two scenarios I would like to speed up:

1. When selecting the XPM Button, the initial loading of the Page (the Breadcrumbs bar takes around 20 seconds to load).
2. When selecting 'Finish Editing', The Commit is fast, but the Page Refresh takes around 30-60 seconds.

I recall seeing (a long time ago) a way to cache some of the XPM files in IIS.  Anyone tried this or have other suggestions of tuning IIS or the XPM WebApp to make it a little faster?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors? Typically, a slow page load may be causing the issue; with or without the AJAX calls from XPM.

Comment: I'm looking to see how I could tune the XPM 'app' in IIS to more aggressively cache content and also provide a better UX....they will migrate to the latest XPM in a few months, but until then to try to make the Experience in XPM 2013 a more pleasant one....